# Impact of Redgate SQL Search on Server

Tags: sql-server, tools

I'm a huge fan of a lot of the [Redgate](http://www.red-gate.com/) tools, however at my current workplace they are very paranoid over anything interacting with live servers (in particular affecting performance).

So my question is specifically on their [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) tool, what impact does it have on a server? I'm assuming that there will be:

1. Initial indexing (what does it interact with, idea on impact on server, can it be customised to not index live servers)
2. Subsequent connections/refreshes (how is it determining if there is a change to be re-indexed and what performance/load impact that will have on a server)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer received from Redgate support:

> Following are answers to your questions:
>
> 1. When you load a database in SQL Search, it indexes and stores the
>      info on cache for giving search results. To not index specific
>      servers, just do not select 'All database' nor pick the database you
>      do not want to index in the database filter.
> 2. Whenever you have mode modifications or want the index to be
>      refreshed, manually refresh the index from the menu in SQL Search.
>
> Hope that helps.
>
> Thanks,   Anuradha Deshpande

Answer (score 5):

[SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) is very useful when it comes to solving problems like this - use the `ApplicationName` filter to trace data specific to a particular application (i.e. SQL Search in this case), capture the data when it is used and then analyze executed queries and their performance.